# Page_Load() save to Database

Tags: c#, sql-server

How can i save to database using Page_Load() in C# I have been trying to save into the MSSQL Database and it just leaves the column very empty and nothing is saved in these columns , I need help here as i am a bit of a novice with ASP.NET

My code looks like this :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string firstname = Request.QueryString["firstname"];
    string lastname = Request.QueryString["lastname"];
    string email = Request.QueryString["email"];

    //Put user code to initialize the page here
    Topaz.SigPlusNET sigObj = new Topaz.SigPlusNET();
    sigObj.AutoKeyStart();

    //use the same data to decrypt signature
    sigObj.SetAutoKeyData(Request.Form["username"]);

    sigObj.AutoKeyFinish();
    sigObj.SetSigCompressionMode(1);
    sigObj.SetEncryptionMode(2);

    //Now, get sigstring from client
    //Sigstring can be stored in a database if 
    //a biometric signature is desired rather than an image
    //sigObj.SetSigString(Request.Form["hidden"]);
    if (sigObj.NumberOfTabletPoints() > 0)
    {
        sigObj.SetImageFileFormat(0);
        sigObj.SetImageXSize(500);
        sigObj.SetImageYSize(150);
        sigObj.SetImagePenWidth(8);
        sigObj.SetJustifyX(5);
        sigObj.SetJustifyY(5);
        sigObj.SetJustifyMode(5);
        System.Drawing.Image img = sigObj.GetSigImage();
        base64ImageString = ImageToBase64(img, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

        if (base64ImageString.Length > 3000)
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
            {
                con.Open();
                string sql = "insert into SakalPicturecontrol (firstname,lastname,email,base64ImageString) Values (@firstname,@lastname,@email,@base64ImageString)";
                try
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", firstname);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", lastname);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@base64ImageString", base64ImageString);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        Response.Write("Information has been saved Correctly..");
                        con.Close();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Response.Write("Error: " + ex.ToString());
                }
            }
        }

    }
    else
    {
        //signature has not been returned successfully!
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get any exception, or the whole code executes without errors?

Comment: So is it inserting a new row, just with all empty values? It's a little unclear what the current behavior is. And are you certain you're actually getting values back from the query string as expected?

Comment: Does it get passed `base64ImageString.Length > 3000`?  BTW, you might want to move the `con.close()` in a `finally` block in case of it hitting the `catch` block. That way it's closed regardless if it worked or not.

Comment: @MarcinTopolewski, nothing , No Error

Comment: @BrootsWaymb, No new column . Doesnt even insert at all.

Comment: Put the try/catch block around the entire piece of code.

Comment: My guess is it falls into your else that you haven't defined yet. Set a break point and figure out what is happening. You might also want to take a peek at this. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/